# Loading harmful webpages by PhantomJS

Tags: security

I've planned to run PhantomJS as a webpage screenshot service. I'm concerned about the security. What if a user asked for a harmful (malware-ful or something like that) webpage screenshot? Can this harm the server?

Comment: Not the one who gave the downvote but it is a bit obvious that if PhantomJS is indeed a complete and functional web browser then it is subject to the same vulnerabilities and security issues that the browser core has. If there is a remote data execution bug in the WebKit core, then your browser has it too and anyone aware of it and targeting it will be able to exploit it to gain potentially unlimited control of your server. After that the question becomes "how to defend" which would be too broad for a question here.

Comment: If you have no idea what could go wrong then you are best off not putting public services on the internet, especially if you are essentially giving unknown people control of a potentially insecure browser on an insecure box that may or may not have sensitive data on it.

Comment: I think this would be a good question for [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The two main threats would be:

1. Exploitation of a Webkit vulnerability, or of a plugin loaded by Webkit/PhantomJS. This could allow arbitrary code execution on your server.
2. Local access to your server. It's very likely that you will allow access to some internal services to localhost only (redis server, DB server, DB administration, tool, etc.). Now your web client can access localhost as well. This extends to any local IP.

There are some other "annoyances" that you'll need to worry about in addition to security issues:

- download of large files that could fill out your HD
- DoS on page that may not be a threat to the website but will be enough to blacklist you
- Trigger security responses by "faking" some kind of attacks (XSS, SQLI, etc.) on some sensitive website (.gov, .mil)
- accessing forbidden content (download torrent file, child pornography, etc.)